# try{} catch{} doesn't function

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

This is the piece of code that performs a check on the values ​​entered in a table of EditText, if I'm wrong to enter the values, shows me the alertdialog properly, I correct the input, press again the button to complete the input and the app crashes, Why?

```
button = new Button(this);
button.setText("Riempi la prima Matrice");
tableLayout.addView(button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    array[t] = Double.parseDouble(values[i][j].getText().toString());
                    t++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondaAttivita.this);
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage("Wrong input format");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }
});​
```

This is a logCat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
it.bisemanuDEV.prodMatrix.SecondaAttivita$1.onClick(SecondaAttivita.java:96)
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the error (stack trace) in logcat?

Comment: i suspect it is not a NumberFormatException that is thrown

Comment: Where is `t` and `array` defined? Is `array[t]` a valid location?

Comment: it is all declared and everything is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your stack trace, when it tries to assign the double to `array[t]`, it fails because the index `t` is not valid for the array `array`.

**edit**: After taking into consideration @Gophermofur's comment, if the rest of your code outside of this snippet is correct, to fix it, reset `t` inside the catch block. e.g. if `t` started as 0, reset it to 0 when the `NumberFormatException` is caught.

**2nd edit**: if the values are allowed to be edited even after accepting correct input, you probably want to stick the reset of `t` into a `finally` block after the catch instead of inside the catch.

Comment: so how do I fix this problem? I'm not very experienced with programming in Android

Comment: Without seeing how `t` and `array` is initialized and used, it's impossible to know. All I know for sure is that when the input is parsed, `t` is out of the bounds of `array` meaning that `t < 0` or `t >= array.length`.

Comment: Couldn't it also occur when processing values[i][j]? If values doesn't have 3 rows with each row having 3 columns, I would guess it would blow up?

Comment: @Gophermofur, yeah, it is. Actually, now that I think about it, the problem is probably that t is incremented after the first attempt that fails, then is incremented again after the 2nd attempt, probably assigning the values into the unintended locations, then when it passes the size of the array, it fails.

Comment: @yincrash I change my mind. I think Yincrash is right. Are you resetting 't' before each validation attempt? It looks like you should be?

Answer (score 2):

If you are unsure of type of exception to catch, then make it general as below:

```
try{
   ...
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: The specific dialog being displayed is only valid for a `NumberFormatException`. I would heavily recommend against catching all `Exception`s with that dialog.

Comment: but he doesnt know what exception to catch. With my solution, at least he can log the exception type to know exactly what to catch

Comment: The problem with your solution is that bugs in the code will not be caught and reported to the developer. Ideally, the developer will want to know about programming errors rather than just showing a dialog displaying an error having nothing to do with the underlying cause. [Here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontCatchRuntimeExceptions) is a reasonable explanation into why you shouldn't just catch all `Exception`s. If you do catch all `Exception`s, you should have appropriate behavior for it.

Comment: I know its better to catch relative type of exception but you didnt get my point. The developer doesnt know what to catch and doesn't even know how to observe logs. and if he follows with his approach, he'll simply get FC... so you decide which one is better...?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it tells you in your error message what type of Exception to catch:

```
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

so

```
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) { }
```